# Symfony 5 keeps redirecting from the register route

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am trying to build a login page register user its working after I wanted to login them in so I used the make: Auth seemed but now Symfony 5 keeps redirecting from the register route to login without saving the users in the DB first when the form is submitted it was working before i ran the make auth cmd

most of the code regaring the user auth

this is the guide i used `https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html`

on the Symfony docs
i guess that's why it messing up

> When you submit the form, the LoginFormAuthenticator will intercept
> the request, read the email (or whatever field you’re using) &
> password from the form, find the User object, validate the CSRF token
> and check the password

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto 
    providers:
        users:
            entity: 
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: Username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
            anonymous: false
            lazy: true
            provider: users
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\AuthAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

`

```
 <?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use App\Security\EmailVerifier;
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use SymfonyCasts\Bundle\VerifyEmail\Exception\VerifyEmailExceptionInterface;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    private $emailVerifier;

    public function __construct(EmailVerifier $emailVerifier)
    {
        $this->emailVerifier = $emailVerifier;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
     */
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassowrd(
                $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // generate a signed url and email it to the user
            $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
                (new TemplatedEmail())
                    ->from(new Address('root@root.com', 'root'))
                    ->to($user->getEmail())
                    ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                    ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
            );
            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/verify/email", name="app_verify_email")
     */
    public function verifyUserEmail(Request $request): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

        // validate email confirmation link, sets User::isVerified=true and persists
        try {
            $this->emailVerifier->handleEmailConfirmation($request, $this->getUser());
        } catch (VerifyEmailExceptionInterface $exception) {
            $this->addFlash('verify_email_error', $exception->getReason());

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
        }

        // @TODO Change the redirect on success and handle or remove the flash message in your templates
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Your email address has been verified.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_register');
    }
}
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% for flashError in app.flashes('verify_email_error') %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ flashError }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

    <h1>Register</h1>

    {{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.Username) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
            label: 'Password'
        }) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.agreeTerms) }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
    {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
{% endblock %}




<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AuthAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'Username' => $request->request->get('Username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['Username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['Username' => $credentials['Username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(' Username could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to lack the csrf_token hidden field on your twig form as is explained on the Symfony doc link you provided : [How to build a login form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html#generating-the-login-form)

```
   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
           value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
    >
```

Although i wouldn't recommend it, another solution if your application is not critical would be to disable csrf_checking - just remove all mentions of CSRF from your AuthAuthenticator.